# UIAppearance, where in UIView lifecycle can I access what I set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

This may be a confusing title but basically; I would like to know at what point in UIView Lifecycle can I access the `someFont` property that I set via `[MyView appearance] setSomeFont:...]`

FWIW

I assign my appearance values inside `AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

and I read them in 
`MyView drawRect:`

If i was to read them at any other point i.e.: `awakeFromNib` (I am using nibs) the property is nil.

Which in some cases doesn't give me the best results i.e.: setting an attributed string in a table cell title (the text is set before the rect has drawn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the apple developer link [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

> Note: iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it
>   doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window.